# how to create a correct not fullscreen camera preview?

Tags: android, android-camera

i am trying to create a camera app. it is mostly based on official tutorial. my problem is to create a not full screen preview with correct aspect ratio. the ["CameraPreview"](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.3.7_r1/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.java) example from sdk creates a fullscreen preview.

the size and aspect ratio wouldnt bother me but the video is also recorded with this wrong aspect ratio.

**Edit for Clarrification:**
I am using "CameraPreview" so i have all the resizing and autosizing in place. If i use it like in example:

```
setContentView(mPreview);
```

i get a working preview but this is fullscreen.

My question is how to integrate this preview class

```
public class CameraPreview extends ViewGroup implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
...
```

in a given layout. i want a small window for preview (preferable resizable). I need to know how to do the overall layout. the problem seems to be that main layout is created first with its children (and sizes) and after that the size for preview is measured.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use this method:

```
private Point computePreviewSize(int pictureWidth, int pictureHeight,
        int screenWidth, int screenHeight){
    int resultWidth;
    int resultHeight;

    double widthRatio = pictureWidth / (double) screenWidth;
    double heightRatio = pictureHeight / (double) screenHeight;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio){
        resultWidth = screenWidth;
        resultHeight = (int) (pictureHeight / widthRatio);
    }
    else{
        resultWidth = (int) (pictureWidth / heightRatio);
        resultHeight = screenHeight;
    }

    return new Point(resultWidth, resultHeight);
}
```

I call it in `SurfaceChanged` (in my camera preview):

```
Point result = computePreviewSize(pictureWidth, pictureHeight, width, height);
holder.setFixedSize(result.x, result.y);
```

It works for me to take a picture. I think it should also work for video.

Comment: thx - but my first problem is how to set up the overall layout - see my edits

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can control your camera preview size using camera parameters like what I used in my camera preview

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                    Preview.this.invalidate();
                }
            });
            LayoutParams lparam = this.getLayoutParams();
            lparam.height = this.getHeight();
            lparam.width =  parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
            parameters.setPreviewSize(lparam.width, lparam.height);
            this.setLayoutParams(lparam);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

you can get also modify the height based on height and width of the screen so you can maintain the aspect ratio. You can achieve that using this function :

```
public static int getDisplayWidth(Context context) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int width = display.getWidth(); 

        return width;
    }

    public static int getDisplayHeight(Context context) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int height = display.getHeight(); 

        return height;
    }
```

and then use it in the surfaceCreated above to determine the camera preview width and height

Comment: thx - but my first problem is how to set up the overall layout - see my edits